# Does the five lemma hold true for Lie algebras?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, lie-algebras, homological-algebra

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_lemma), the Five Lemma is true in Abelian categories. But [the category of Lie algebras is not Abelian](http://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2012/08/14/the-category-of-lie-algebras-is-not-quite-abelian/). Then is the Five Lemma still true for Lie Algebras?

Comment: If you replace "epimorphism" by "surjective map" then you can use the $5$ lemma from the category of vector spaces.  But in general I'm not sure if Lie algebra epi's are necessarily surjective.  I would guess not and I would guess that this breaks the $5$ lemma.

Comment: In the link it is claimed that $\mathsf{LieAlg}$ is an $\mathsf{Ab}$-category. Is this true? If $f,g : L \to L'$ is a homomorphism, then I don't see why $f+g$ defined by $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ is again a Lie algebra homomorphism. This is quite similar to the observation that $\mathsf{Alg}$ is not an $\mathsf{Ab}$-category. In the link it is also implicitly claimed that what is usually called the direct sum of Lie algebras is the coproduct. But this is wrong. The "direct sum" of two lie algebras classifies two "orthogonal" homomorphisms. PS: Ah, Qiaochu Yuan remarked the same.

Comment: However, the category of Lie algebras is a [semi-abelian category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semi-abelian+category).

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! @ZhenLin, is the five-lemma true for semi-abelian category?